# bash - how to automatically send SIGINT on matching line in stdout

Tags: bash, pipe, stdout, sigint

Given: A `foo_command` that runs as the last line of a script I control. I don't control `foo_command`.

I'm looking for something like:

```sh
foo_command | interrupt_if_grep "warning"
```

`foo_command` prints progress and sometimes warnings to stdout. I'd like to have `interrupt_if_grep` passthrough stdout, but send SIGINT to `foo_command` if it encounters a matching warning line, i.e. what I would do manually.

To summarize all the cases, `foo_command` can:

1. succeed - I want to passthrough stdout as normal
2. warning to stdout, then succeed - I want to detect warning and SIGINT (returning error)
3. error - I want script to error as normal

Some things I tried that don't work for me:

```sh
# foo_command doesn't handle SIGPIPE properly and this suppresses normal stdout output
foo_command | grep -m1 "warning" && exit 1

# error code of `foo_command` is "lost"
foo_command | tee foo_stdout.txt
! grep "warning" foo_stdout.txt  # error if "warning" is found
```

Comment: few clarifications needed 1. What do you mean by 'foo_command doesn't handle SIGPIPE properly and this suppresses normal stdout output'? - SIGPIPE does not kill it? 2. Could you add more on ' I'd also like everything to error if foo_command errors'?

Comment: would `expect` be an acceptable solution for you ?

Comment: also, how would you retrieve the error code of the `foo_command` ? If I understood corectly, if you want to manually kill the process yourself, you'll always have the same error code. Do you retrieve the code from stdout ? If so, could you show an example ?

Comment: @Inian `foo_command` happens to be a Python script. SIGPIPE does kill, but prints stacktrace b/c `BrokenPipeError` isn't handled. I suppose that's _okay_ if other desired behavior is intact. Updated with case summary.

Comment: @Aserre I don't need the error code per se, more that as the last line of the script, the script errors if `foo_command` errors. In cases I want to `SIGINT`, I do want it to error (where it currently only prints warnings).

Answer (score 0):

The second solution you tried would work with the `pipefail` option enabled, I think:

```sh
set -o pipefail
foo_command | tee foo_stdout.txt || exit 1
! grep "warning" foo_stdout.txt
```

Comment: Just chain the 3 lines with semicolons, then.

Comment: I'll try this out. I said "script", but I think this is all actually getting passed into a bash -c "" down the line. Why the `|| exit 1` though? Wouldn't that make it always exit/error?